# Base64 sourced IFrame not displaying in mobile/responsive screens and devices

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, dom, iframe

I am using an IFrame to display a PDF which is sourced from a Base64 byte string. My frame tag looks like the below (I'm using Angular).

```
<iframe id="pdfV" type="application/pdf" [src]="currentBase64"></iframe>
```

The `currentBase64` variable starts with `data:application/pdf;base64`, and has been appropriately sanitized. On any browser it works great. However, when I am in responsive mode in Chrome, or viewing on a phone, it doesn't display the frame for some reason. The only other example I can provide is the below

http://pdfmake.org/playground.html

This playground is doing the same thing I am. Passing Base64 to IFrame to display PDF. Notice is works great until you put the screen into responsive mode -- at that point it stops refreshing.

I believe it has to do with the Base64 part of it all because when I change my frame tag to something simple such as the below it works great, even on mobile devices.

```
<iframe [src]="'https://www.google.com'"></iframe>
```

Any thoughts or solutions?